# Allocating array in a for-loop outputting nonsense

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array of integers of fixed size but when filling the array somethings get messed up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY   5

int main(void) {

   int * myArr;
   myArr= (int*)malloc(SIZE_OF_ARRAY * sizeof(int));

   if (myArr == NULL) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   for (int i = 0;i<SIZE_OF_ARRAY;i++) {
       *(myArr +1)=i;
       printf("myArr[%d]= %d\n", i, myArr[i]);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

outputs

```
myArr[0]= 0
myArr[1]= 1
myArr[2]= 0
myArr[3]= 805306368
myArr[4]= -1739194352
```

Why is the allocation working only up to the 2nd index of the array?

Answer (score 2):

You do not initialize elements of your array. All assignments are done to the element `[1]` here:

```
*(myArr +1)=i;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `*(myArr +1)=i;`
with `*(myArr + i) = i;`

Answer (score 2):

`*(myArr +1)` is element 1 of the array. You may have intended `*(myArr +i)`.

Answer (score 2):

tooo little coffee today

```
*(myArr +i)=i;
```

or

```
myArr[i]=i;
```

does the job

Answer (score 1):

Meant to be `*(myArr + i) = i` (or just `myArr[i] = i`)?

With the constant +1 offset, *the current code will only ever change the 2nd element*.

The 1st element evaluates to 0 “by chance” as it never had a value assigned, which might falsely contribute to supporting the initial assertion..